# Django: Use ImageField in Modelforms

Tags: django-models, django-forms, imagefield

So I have this model forms:

```
User = get_user_model()
class UserRegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(label='', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Username'}))
    email = forms.EmailField(label='', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email Address'}))
    email2 = forms.EmailField(label='', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Confirm Email'}))
    password = forms.CharField(label='', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password'}))
    avatar = forms.ImageField(upload_to='profile_images')

class Meta:
    model = User 
    fields = [
        'username',
        'email',
        'email2',
        'password'
    ]
```

But this appear

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'upload_to'
```

The problem is that I think it will works if I add the ImageField object to the model, but I dont have a model, As you can see I am using the get_user_model(), is there a way to use upload_to in model forms, or how can I add to the default 'get_user_model' the ImageField object?

Comment: You don't write this in the `User` model, but in the model where you target to write the image. The standard `User` model has no `avatar`, but if you use a `Profile`, you should write it there.

Comment: A form does not specify how to *persist* data, a model does. A form validates user input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make an extra model then to store the avatar, or you can make a [custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model).

If you make an extra model, for example `Profile`, you can define this as:

```
# app/models.py

from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        editable=False
    )
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_images/')
```

Then you can make two `ModelForm`s for example. In fact for the `User`, you better use the [**`UserCreationForm`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm), since this already implements logic to validate if the passwords match, and it will also transparently hash the password.

You thus can define a `ModelForm` for the `Profile`, and work with:

```
# app/forms.py

from django import forms
from app.models import Profile

class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['avatar']
```

In the view, you then work with two forms:

```
# app/views.py

from app.forms import ProfileForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

def some_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        form2 = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            form2.instance.user = user
            form2.save()
            return redirect('name-of-some-other-view')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
        form2 = ProfileForm()
    return render(request, 'name-of-some-template.html', {'form': form, 'form2': form2})
```

and you thus render both forms in the same `<form>` tag:

```
<form action="{% url 'some_view' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    {{ form2 }}
</form>
```

Comment: if I already have the User model how can I add another user model to store the avatar?

Comment: @BernardoOlivera: this is exactly the scope if this answer, since here we create an extra user model `Profile` to store the avatar, and make a *reference* (a `OneToOneField`) from `Profile` to the `User`.

Comment: Yes okey, now I understand much better

Comment: One last question, so If I do that I dont need to make the media_url and that stuff?

Comment: @BernardoOlivera: during development you can indeed let Django serve static/media files, see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development

But during production, you need to configure nginx/apache/... to serve static/media files.

Comment: Also, How can I access the profile image in my template?

Comment: @BernardoOlivera: if you have a user, you can use `{{ user.profile.avatar.url }}`, to obtain the media url. So if you have a `Post` model for example with a `ForeignKey` to the user, then for a `post` object, you can use `{{ post.user.profile.avatar.url }}`.